# Minimal GCC build

Tags: c, gcc, build

I would like to build a very minimal subset of GCC (4.9), basically I just need the C compiler (a statically linked binary would be perfect). The whole GCC build system seems to be extremely complex and there's no documentation regarding a minimal build. I've spend more than an hour reading the documentation on configuring and building GCC, but I'm not happy with my result yet.

The `./configure` options I have so far are the following:

- `--enable-languages=c`
- `--disable-bootstrap`
- `--disable-multilib`
- `--disable-nls`

After build and installation, I still see tons of files in the directory `/usr/local/share/locale`, so I have no idea what `--disable-nls` was about. I'm also wondering about the contents of the directory `/usr/local/lib/gcc/*/[gcc-version]`, is it really needed?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IIRC it doesn't link the library against libintl or tries to build libintl sources as part of the GCC tree.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html), `--disable-nls` is indeed the correct switch for disabling localizations:

> The `--enable-nls` option enables Native Language Support (NLS), which lets GCC output diagnostics in languages other than American English. Native Language Support is enabled by default if not doing a canadian cross build. The `--disable-nls` option disables NLS.

It's possible that the option is broken. You can delete the content of `/usr/local/share/locale` **if it really is only from GCC!** Double check that! You probably don't want to delete localizations of other programs (unless you don't care about them either, of course).

The files in `/usr/local/lib/gcc/*/[gcc-version]` are very, **very important**! They contain internal files, for example the actual compiler `cc1` and the linker helper `collect2`. You'll also find "fixed" versions of some header files there which will override system headers (these are headers that GCC considers to broken in some way and that it fixed; sometimes these "fixes" can actually get into your way but usually you don't want to mess with these files either).

Comment: `cc1` and `collect2` are actually in the directory `/usr/local/libexec/*`, not `/usr/local/lib/*`. Is there a way to disable these "fixed" header files? The assumption of having broken headers on the system is the wrong way to go, in my point of view.

Comment: You can simply delete the "fixed" header files but I'm pretty sure the GCC guys don't do it just for fun. There surely is a very good reason they do this. One reason I see is that it's a really bad idea to mess with the actual system headers (especially when you install several GCC versions in parallel which might support different C/C++ features).

Comment: In regards to DarkDust: the GCC team trying to "fix" headers has led to many issues in the past; you can search for this on google and find many examples for that. I myself have run into intransparent issues in regards to #include_next (my filesystem layout is non-standard, e. g. more of a pure variant of GoboLinux, and GCC makes assumptions that are not applicable in my case, so I have to change these assumptions by editing some files before starting to compile GCC. I'd wish it were more flexible to begin with.)